# Azure Point to Site - Is this possible?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network, virtual-network

Just want to see if I can achieve this using Azure Point to Site networking.

## Network A

Closed enterprise network (private) cannot be accessed from outside (internet) and I have On-Premises database and other resources accessible on a machine (Machine A) within this Network.

## Question

If I create a point to site Azure network from the Machine A to Azure and add VM's to Azure network, can I access the On-Premises database from the VM in Azure Virtual network?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I create a point to site Azure network from the Machine A to Azure
>   and add VM's to Azure network, can I access the On-Premises database
>   from the VM in Azure Virtual network?

Yes, you can access the On-premise database from Azure VM.

I did a test in my Lab.  I found that after connecting your on-premise machine to Azure P2S VPN, you would get a Virtual IP from the P2S address pool:

[image]

So, if you want to access your on-premise machine from Azure AM , you need to use this virtual private IP address.

I can use this VIP to access the on-premise machine :

[image]

Comment: Excellent, Thanks for sharing your experience.